# CSS not updating with aggregation turned off

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

I'm running into an issue that I'm not sure how to diagnose. I'm working on minor CSS updates on a custom zen theme for a Drupal 7 site. I have the dev site set up on a laptop running ubuntu dev server. I have gone to performance and turned off css and js aggregation and flushed all the caches via Drush. The problem I'm having is that my css changes are being saved to the styles.css file, but they're not reflected when I refresh the site. Poking around in inspector, the css files have a `?oegwy2` suffix, which suggests that something is still aggregating or modifying the files. I'm not sure what that would be, I didn't set up sass for the this project, so the sass recompiling isn't likely what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS file may still be being cached, even if not aggregated.
You can refresh the `?oegwy2` querystring with drush

```
drush cc css-js
```

Which refreshes the config variable: `css_js_query_string`

You could also add the following to your dev env settings.php to disable that querystring var:

```
$conf['css_js_query_string'] = '';
```

Then you should be able to just use hard reload (e.g Shift+Refresh) to refresh the CSS.